# ComponentActivity vs AppCompatActivity in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-jetpack-compose

When using Jetpack Compose, by default it extends the `ComponentActivity` class. But after trying some samples I switched to `AppCompatActivity` and everything seemed to work fine. So I wonder what the difference between these is. Do any additional features come with `ComponentActivity`?

Comment: And also what is the difference between `ComponentActivity` in **androidx.activity** package vs **androidx.core.app** package?

Comment: You cannot access it as it is marked with library-level access annotation

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` which extends `ComponentActivity`.

`ComponentActivity` has all you need for a **Compose-only** app.
If you need AppCompat APIs, an `AndroidView` which works with AppCompat or MaterialComponents theme, or you need `Fragment`s then use `AppCompatActivity`.

**Note**: it requires at least the AppCompat `1.3.0` version.

Comment: Can we use setLocalNightMode in Componenet activity. If so, how can we do it in compose otherwise what is the alternative.

Comment: marked as the answer!

Comment: When did Google add ComponentActivity?

Comment: In version `1.0.0-alpha01` https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.0.0-alpha01