# How to use the new ComponentActivity with ViewBinding and the other old AppCompatActivity components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-menu

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71917856/4205927), I tried to update my deprecated menus codes like <s>**`setHasOptionsMenu`**</s>  , **`onCreateOptionsMenu`** and **`onOptionsItemSelected`** in my fragments and all app, but I should replace `AppCompatActivity` to `ComponentActivity(R.layout.activity_example)` but after doing this I see there's some problem, first I confused about how to use ViewBinding with it when I should remove `setContentView(binding.root)` from activity second the method `setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)` is not found, and I couldn't use the  navigation components like `supportFragmentManager` and `setupActionBarWithNavController`
the third thing I couldn't"t declare this 
 `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` in `onCreateView` in fragment I see it's Required:
MenuHost
but Found:
FragmentActivity

[image]

[image: menu updates]

here's my **MainActivity** code before edits

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var postViewModel: PostViewModel
    private lateinit var navGraph: NavGraph


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        postViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[PostViewModel::class.java]
        postViewModel.getCurrentDestination()

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?

        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            navController = navHostFragment.navController
        }
        navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_accessory,
                R.id.nav_arcade, R.id.nav_fashion,
                R.id.nav_food, R.id.nav_heath,
                R.id.nav_lifestyle, R.id.nav_sports, R.id.nav_favorites, R.id.about
            ), drawerLayout
        )
//        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
//        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
        setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)



        
//        determineAdvertisingInfo()
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

}
```

and this the implementation of menus in fragments

```
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


         setHasOptionsMenu(true)
         return binding.root
    }

....................................................................................

  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        val searchManager =
            requireContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(requireActivity().componentName))
        searchView.queryHint = resources.getString(R.string.searchForPosts)

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(keyword: String): Boolean {
                if (keyword.isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        requireView(),
                        "please enter keyword to search",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
//                itemArrayList.clear()
                if (Utils.hasInternetConnection(requireContext())) {
                    postViewModel.getItemsBySearch(keyword)
                    postViewModel.searchedPostsResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->

                        when (response) {
                            is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                                hideShimmerEffect()
                                itemArrayList.clear()
                                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                                response.data?.let {
                                    itemArrayList.addAll(it.items)
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                            }

                            is NetworkResult.Error -> {
                                hideShimmerEffect()
                                //                    loadDataFromCache()
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    response.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()

                            }

                            is NetworkResult.Loading -> {
                                if (postViewModel.recyclerViewLayout.value == "titleLayout" ||
                                    postViewModel.recyclerViewLayout.value == "gridLayout"
                                ) {
                                    hideShimmerEffect()
                                } else {
                                    showShimmerEffect()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    postViewModel.getItemsBySearchInDB(keyword)
                    postViewModel.postsBySearchInDB.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { items ->
                        if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
                            hideShimmerEffect()
                            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            itemArrayList.clear()
                            itemArrayList.addAll(items)
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false

            }


            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
        searchView.setOnCloseListener {
            if (Utils.hasInternetConnection(requireContext())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "setOnCloseListener: called")
                itemArrayList.clear()
                requestApiData()
            } else {
                noInternetConnectionLayout()
            }
            false
        }


        postViewModel.searchError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { searchError ->
            if (searchError) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "There's no posts with this keyword", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }

    }



   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.change_layout) {
            changeAndSaveLayout()
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'

    implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1') {
        exclude(group: 'androidx.recyclerview',  module: 'recyclerview')
        exclude(group: 'androidx.recyclerview',  module: 'recyclerview-selection')
    }
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

//    //Moshi
//    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0")
//    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")
//    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2"




    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42'


    //SDP & SSP
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    // Shimmer
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    //firebase & analytics
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    //crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // DataStore
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava3:1.0.0")

    //admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')

    implementation project(':nativetemplates')

    implementation("androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha04")

    // Used for the calls to addCallback() in the snippets on this page.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android")

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.0")


}
```

Comment: AppCompatActivity extends ComponentActivity, so just keep using AppCompatActivity.

Comment: And putting the layout in the superconstructor call is just an alternative to using `setContentView()`. If you choose to use the superconstructor way of doing it, you need to use your binding's `bind()` function instead of its `inflate()` function to bind to the already-inflated view. If you're using view binding, it's probably simpler to do it using `inflate` instead of passing the layout to the superconstructor.

Comment: @ianhanniballake If I keep using AppCompatActivity then How can I use the new menus implementation in fragment? `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()` it is related with extended of ComponentActivity ?

Comment: You'd have to be using a very, very, very old version of AppCompat and Fragment to not have `FragmentActivity` and `AppCompatActivity` extend `ComponentActivity`. Please include the `dependencies` block from your `build.gradle` file if you'd like us to look at what versions you are using.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I edited my question and add dependencies block, please check

Comment: Yep, your `FragmentActivity` definitely extends `ComponentActivity` and therefore has access to the `MenuHost` interface that `ComponentActivity` implements.

Comment: @ianhanniballake no all fragment extends the regular fragment class `androidx.fragment.app`, If I would update to last menus API, I implement `MenuProvider` but the only problem now is I can't declare this `val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution from top of my head (hopefully it will work for you):

```
val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity() as MenuHost
```

This example is for fragment but I guess you can easily apply it to activity:

First extend fragment with ***MenuProvider***:

```
class SomeFragment : SomethingIfYouHave(), MenuProvider { /* Your code */ }
```

Now in ***onCreateView***:

```
val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity() as MenuHost
menuHost.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
```

Later in code override ***onCreateMenu*** and ***onMenuItemSelected***.

```
override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.info_menu, menu)
}
    
override fun onMenuItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.something-> {
            // Do something here
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

***AppCompatActivity*** extends ***FragmentActivity*** which extends ***ComponentActivity***, why to use ***ComponentActivity*** directly?

Please revert it to:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { /* Your code here */ }
```

I think your only problem was in this line:

```
val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity() as MenuHost
```

***------------------- UPDATE***

*ComponentActivity has all you need for a Compose-only app.
If you need AppCompat APIs, an AndroidView which works with AppCompat or MaterialComponents theme, or you need Fragments then use AppCompatActivity.

- [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891505/10810339)*

You are not using purely **ComposeUI**, so that is why you need ***AppCompat*** and not ***ComponentActivity***.

If you want to use ***ComponentActivity*** without ***AppCompat*** you need to get rid off ***supportFragmentManager***.

This would go out of the scope but please check [ComposeUI Fragments](https://sonique6784.medium.com/jetpack-compose-and-the-fall-of-fragments-54bf9977da1a) if you want to switch on ComposeUI (I didn't write article).

Comment: @gaming-ingrs thank you, so the trick for this problem was in casting `as MenuHost` simple like that :D , so to complete the answer to this question Can you edit your answer and add how to use the `ComponentActivity(R.layout.activity_example)` in activity with viewBinding and `setSupportActionBar` and `supportFragmentManager` because I used this in my app

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to use ComponentActivity directly as AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity which extends ComponentActivity? You should revert it to AppCompatActivity and if you have any error after that please let me know.

Comment: Updated my answer based on my comment above so please check it out.

Comment: @gaming-ingrs I am not sure if you understand my previous reply, but you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965674/7639296) to relate
He used `class ExampleActivity : ComponentActivity(R.layout.activity_example)` in activity so I thought to use new menus API "Using the addMenuProvider() API directly in your Activity" it should extend `ComponentActivity` not `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Please check my update.