# Biometric Authentication in jetpack compose

Tags: authentication, android-jetpack-compose, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

In my Android app, I have an activity that extends ComponentActivity and includes multiple Jetpack Compose composable functions. One of these composable functions is accessed by the user, and I want to show a biometric prompt for fingerprint authentication before allowing access to that particular function.

I'm facing issues because I'm using ComponentActivity, and most of the examples I found use FragmentActivity with fragments.

How can I integrate a biometric prompt into a Jetpack Compose composable function within a ComponentActivity? Is there a way to achieve this without using fragments?

Comment: You can use `AppCompatActivity` instead.
See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891505/2215114